# Where did I go wrong to get this error: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

This is my code, and when it run, I get this error `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`.

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 30)

pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

df = pd.read_csv('survey.csv')

df['treatment'].replace({'Yes': 1, 'No': '0'}, inplace=True)

df['family_history'].replace({'Yes': 1, 'No': '0'}, inplace=True)

ztest, pval = sm.stats.ztest(df['family_history'], df['treatment'],value=0)
```

Comment: Add description and stack trace. Read about [Minimal and Reproducible Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and correct the code to demonstrate the issue at hand. And always check first if a similar question has not already been published.

Comment: Where are you concatenating? Please show the command which is failing.

Comment: Try `{'Yes': 1, 'No': 0}` instead of `'0'`.

Comment: @KM_83: Shouldn't it be the other way round?  `{'Yes': '1', 'No':'0'}` ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the error is thrown because `df['treatment']` and `df['family_history']` are of type `str` and you are replacing with `int` values. Try this:

```
df['treatment'].replace({'Yes': '1', 'No': '0'}, inplace=True)
df['family_history'].replace({'Yes': '1', 'No': '0'}, inplace=True)
```

You can also convert the column values to `int` if need be after replacing.

```
df['treatment'] = df['treatment'].astype(int)
df['family_history'] = df['family_history'].astype(int)
```